# Is there a way of having a textbox with "A. " locked in however you can still type in after this?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I need to have a textbox which a user can type into however they cannot edit some words in the textbox. I know I could use a label or two textboxes with one locked however id prefer to only have one, is this possible?

Comment: Does "A." will always be the 2 first characters of the textbox ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want the A. there in a user input field? Are you using it for something later on? Otherwise you could just add a label beside the textbox that the user cannot alter. You also have the option of just storing the A inside the .Tag property of the textbox if you need to know that the entry relates to A.

Answer (score 0):

If **"A."** will always be the 2 first characters of your textBox, then you can use the `TextBox.KeyPress` event :

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    ' Get the current index of your cursor in the textBox
    Dim index As Integer = TextBox.SelectionStart

    If index <= 2 Then
        If e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Then    
            ' Cancel the deletion
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the same principle for the "suppress" key.
You can prevent the user to paste on the TextBox or select all the text, etc...

You can initialize the TextBox with **"A."** with the code `TextBox.Text = "A."`

Comment: What happens if I select everything in the textbox and type? Wouldn't that just overwrite the A.? Or better yet, I use the arrow keys or mouse to move to the front of the text and press delete. If it can be done, you can bet that some user is going to do it and if your code depends on those first 2 characters, your code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work well. You can define any 'prefix' text you want into a string var or const, initialize the textbox text in form_load and include the below code in the TextBox's KeyDown event.

The Keydown code protects the 'prefix' text by suppressing backspacing/deleting of the prefix text, as well as preventing typed text from starting within the prefix text by checking and modifying the SelectionStart property. Effectively it 'pushes' typed or selected text past the prefix text if the insertion point or selection start is within the prefix text.

```
Public Class Form1
    Const PREFIX As String = "A. "

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.Text = PREFIX
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        If tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength <= PREFIX.Length And (e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete) Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If tb.SelectionStart <= PREFIX.Length Then tb.SelectionStart = PREFIX.Length
    End Sub

End Class
```

You could also get fancy and sub-class the textbox control to incorporate this logic. You could add a 'Prefix' (string) property and override the OnKeyDown event with the keydown logic.

Another way to get fancy, if you want to avoid placing KeyDown code in every textbox, is to 'decorate' the textbox control once with an external class that implements the keydown logic.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _tbPrefix As TBPrefix

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _tbPrefix = New TBPrefix(Me.TextBox1, "A. ")
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TBPrefix
    Protected WithEvents _tb As TextBox
    Protected _prefix As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef TB As TextBox, Prefix As String)
        _tb = TB
        _prefix = Prefix
        If _tb IsNot Nothing Then _tb.Text = _prefix
    End Sub

    Public Property Prefix As String
        Get
            Return _prefix
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _prefix = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property TextBox As TextBox
        Get
            Return _tb
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles _tb.KeyDown
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        If tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength <= Prefix.Length And (e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete) Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If tb.SelectionStart <= Prefix.Length Then tb.SelectionStart = Prefix.Length
    End Sub

End Class
```

The benefit of this approach is that it avoids the need to subclass and allows the assignment of the prefix label text in one step.  It can easily be applied to as many textboxes as needed.  It can also be adapted to work with other controls such as comboboxes.

This decorator class provides some 'convenience' properties, the prefix text can be modified via the 'Prefix' property, and the decorated textbox control is exposed through the readonly TextBox property.

If you want to be really efficient, and you are not otherwise using the 'Tag' property of the textbox, you can avoid declaring a class-scoped field for the decorator and instead do this:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.Tag = New TBPrefix(Me.TextBox1, "A. ")
    End Sub
```